# Why does Rails Postgresql not allow me to start my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am currently trying to deploy my Rails application through Heroku. In order to do so, I needed to switch to postgresql from sqlite3. I did so and tried test running the app by doing "rails s." However, I get the following error on my browser:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

It also shows that the error occurred here:

```
    ### Convenience alias for PG::Connection.new.
    def self::connect( *args )
        return PG::Connection.new( *args ) <<< (error in this line)
    end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the above method in the first place? Setting up PostgreSQL on Heroku usually doesn't need any additional method and complex configuration. What tutorial did you follow? The official one on Heroku how to add PostgreSQL on Heroku at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how Postgres is installed, sounds like you need to restart Postgres.

**Using brew**:

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

**Using asdf**:

```
pg_ctl stop
pg_ctl start
```

Sometimes you might need to reinstall the `pg` gem.